# Some of the tagged questions are not clickable

Tags: support, ignored-tags

Please see below image(i.e the 3rd row). Everything is working fine earlier. But from last few days I have found that I am not able to check some of questions. I do not understand why.[image]

Comment: Crystal ball says one of the tags on that question is in your "Ignored Tags" list.

Comment: OH, Let me check.

Comment: [Drum roll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itAOGRiYRLI).

Comment: @CodyGray Yes it works. Thanks!.